# Matplotlib - Subplot not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to turn a normal plot into a subplot. Here's the code for the plot, which works:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


d = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'B': [-2.5, -1.00, .25, 1.56, .75, 1.20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

x = np.arange(0, 999, 0.1)

y1 = -.75
y2 = .75

plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='lawngreen', alpha='.6')


plt.scatter(df.A, df.B)
plt.plot(df.A, df.B)
plt.axhline(y=0, color='black')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 999))
plt.ylim([-4, 4])
plt.xlim([0, df.A.max() + 1])

plt.show()
```

Then here's what I tried to make it into a subplot. The console doesn't throw any errors, it's just not showing any plot.

```
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.arange(0, 999, 0.1)

y1 = -.75
y2 = .75
ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='lawngreen', alpha='.6')

ax.scatter(df.A, df.B)
ax.plot(df.A, df.B)

ax.axhline(y=0, color='black')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 999))
ax.set_ylim([-4, 4])
ax.set_xlim([0, df.A.max() + 1])
plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fig = plt.figure()` instead of `fig = Figure()`.

Your code would be:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.arange(0, 999, 0.1)

y1 = -.75
y2 = .75
ax.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='lawngreen', alpha='.6')

ax.scatter(df.A, df.B)
ax.plot(df.A, df.B)

ax.axhline(y=0, color='black')
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 999))
ax.set_ylim([-4, 4])
ax.set_xlim([0, df.A.max() + 1])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]